# trinidad custom error message

Tags: jsf, trinidad

I'm using trinidad input date component. I need to override the error message provided by the component.

This is the error message provided by the component,
Enter a date in the same format as this example: 29/11/1998

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a message bundle (for each language you want to support) to your `faces-config.xml`:

```
<application>
  <locale-config>
    <default-locale>en</default-locale>
    <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
  </locale-config>
  <message-bundle>
    messages
  </message-bundle>
</application>
```

And add the corresponding properties file for your message bundle to your application resources:

```
messages.properties
```

If you are using Maven, make sure you add (if it's not there already) the resource folder to the `build` section of your `pom.xml`.

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

If you only want to customize the specific `DateTimeConverter` message, you could only put the following line in your properties file:

```
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.DateTimeConverter.CONVERT_DATE_detail=How cute, but it's wrong!
```

You can use the following parameters in your message:

- {0} the label that identifies the component
- {1} value entered by the user
- {2} an example of the format the converter is expecting

If you want to customize all messages you need the following lines:

```
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.UIXEditableValue.REQUIRED=A value is required.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.UIXEditableValue.REQUIRED_detail=You must enter a value.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.UIXSelectMany.REQUIRED=A selection is required.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.UIXSelectMany.REQUIRED_detail=You must make at least one selection.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.UIXSelectOne.REQUIRED=A selection is required.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.UIXSelectOne.REQUIRED_detail=You must make a selection.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.UIXTableSelectOne.REQUIRED=A row selection is required.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.UIXTableSelectOne.REQUIRED_detail=You must select a row.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.UIXTableSelectMany.REQUIRED=A row selection is required.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.UIXTableSelectMany.REQUIRED_detail=You must select one or more rows.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.UIXSelectMany.UNSUPPORTED_MODEL_TYPE=Unsupported model type.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.UIXSelectMany.UNSUPPORTED_MODEL_TYPE_detail=SelectMany does not support a model of type {0}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.UIXEditableValue.CONVERSION=The value is not the in correct format.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.UIXEditableValue.CONVERSION_detail=Enter a value that matches this pattern: {2}
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.UPLOAD=The file is too large.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.UPLOAD_detail=The file could not be uploaded because it is too large.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.RangeValidator.MAXIMUM_HINT=Enter a number less than or equal to {0}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.RangeValidator.MINIMUM_HINT=Enter a number greater than or equal to {0}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.RangeValidator.RANGE_HINT=Enter a number between {0} and {1}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.LengthValidator.MAXIMUM_HINT=Enter {0} or fewer characters.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.LengthValidator.MINIMUM_HINT=Enter {0} or more characters.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.LengthValidator.EXACT_HINT=Enter {0} characters.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.LengthValidator.RANGE_HINT=Enter between {0} and {1} characters.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.DateTimeRangeValidator.MAXIMUM_HINT=Enter a date on or before {0}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.DateTimeRangeValidator.MINIMUM_HINT=Enter a date on or after {0}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.DateTimeRangeValidator.RANGE_HINT=Enter a date between {0} and {1}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.DateRestrictionValidator.WEEKDAY_HINT=Enter a date that falls on one of the following days: {0}
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.DateRestrictionValidator.MONTH_HINT=Enter a date from one of the following months: {0}
javax.faces.validator.LongRangeValidator.MINIMUM=The number is too low.
javax.faces.validator.LongRangeValidator.MINIMUM_detail=The number must be greater than or equal to {2}.
javax.faces.validator.LongRangeValidator.MAXIMUM=The number is too high.
javax.faces.validator.LongRangeValidator.MAXIMUM_detail=The number must be less than or equal to {2}.
javax.faces.LongRange=The number is not a whole number.
javax.faces.LongRange_detail=Enter a whole number.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.ByteLengthValidator.MAXIMUM=The value is too long.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.ByteLengthValidator.MAXIMUM_detail=Enter a value that is not more than {2} bytes long.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.DateTimeRangeValidator.MAXIMUM=The date is after the valid range.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.DateTimeRangeValidator.MAXIMUM_detail=The date must be on or before {2}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.DateTimeRangeValidator.MINIMUM=The date is before the valid range.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.DateTimeRangeValidator.MINIMUM_detail=The date must be on or after {2}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.DateTimeRangeValidator.NOT_IN_RANGE=The date is outside the valid range.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.DateTimeRangeValidator.NOT_IN_RANGE_detail=The date must be between {2} and {3}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.DateRestrictionValidator.DAY=The date is not valid.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.DateRestrictionValidator.DAY_detail=Enter one of the valid dates.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.DateRestrictionValidator.MONTH=Dates in this month are not valid.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.DateRestrictionValidator.MONTH_detail=Enter a date in one of the following months: {2}
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.DateRestrictionValidator.WEEKDAY=The day of the week for this date is not valid.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.DateRestrictionValidator.WEEKDAY_detail=Enter a date that is on one of the following days: {2}
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.DoubleRangeValidator.MAXIMUM=The number is too high.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.DoubleRangeValidator.MAXIMUM_detail=The number must be less than or equal to {2}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.DoubleRangeValidator.MINIMUM=The number is too low.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.DoubleRangeValidator.MINIMUM_detail=The number must be greater than or equal to {2}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.DoubleRangeValidator.NOT_IN_RANGE=The number is outside the valid range.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.DoubleRangeValidator.NOT_IN_RANGE_detail=The number must be between {2} and {3}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.LengthValidator.MAXIMUM=There are too many characters.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.LengthValidator.MAXIMUM_detail=Enter {2} or fewer characters, not more.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.LengthValidator.MINIMUM=There are too few characters.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.LengthValidator.MINIMUM_detail=Enter {2} or more characters, not fewer.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.LengthValidator.NOT_IN_RANGE=The number of characters is out of range.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.LengthValidator.NOT_IN_RANGE_detail=Enter {2} or more characters, up to a maximum of {3}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.LengthValidator.EXACT=The number of characters is incorrect.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.LengthValidator.EXACT_detail=Enter exactly {2} characters.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.LongRangeValidator.MAXIMUM=The number is too high.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.LongRangeValidator.MAXIMUM_detail=The number must be less than or equal to {2}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.LongRangeValidator.MINIMUM=The number is too low.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.LongRangeValidator.MINIMUM_detail=The number must be greater than or equal to {2}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.LongRangeValidator.NOT_IN_RANGE=The number is out of range.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.LongRangeValidator.NOT_IN_RANGE_detail=The number must be between {2} and {3}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.RegExpValidator.NO_MATCH=The format is incorrect.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.validator.RegExpValidator.NO_MATCH_detail=The value must match this pattern: {2}
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.DateTimeConverter.DATE_HINT=Example: {0}
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.DateTimeConverter.TIME_HINT=Example: {0}
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.DateTimeConverter.BOTH_HINT=Example format: {0}
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.ColorConverter.FORMAT_HINT=Example format: {0}
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.NumberConverter.FORMAT_HINT=Example format: {0}
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.DateTimeConverter.CONVERT_DATE=The date is not in the correct format.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.DateTimeConverter.CONVERT_DATE_detail=Enter a date in the same format as this example: {2}
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.DateTimeConverter.CONVERT_TIME=The time is not in the correct format.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.DateTimeConverter.CONVERT_TIME_detail=Enter a time in the same format as this example: {2}
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.DateTimeConverter.CONVERT_BOTH=The date and time is not in the correct format.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.DateTimeConverter.CONVERT_BOTH_detail=Enter a date and time in the same format as this example: {2}
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.DateTimeConverter.CONVERT_DATE_INVALID_DATE=The date or time entered is not valid.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.DateTimeConverter.CONVERT_DATE_INVALID_DATE_detail=Enter a valid date or time.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.ColorConverter.CONVERT=The color is not in the correct format.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.ColorConverter.CONVERT_detail=Enter a color in the same format as this example: {2}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.ColorConverter.TRANSPARENT=Transparent
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.IntegerConverter.CONVERT=The number is not a whole number.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.IntegerConverter.CONVERT_detail=Enter a whole number.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.IntegerConverter.MINIMUM=The number is too low.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.IntegerConverter.MINIMUM_detail=The number must be greater than or equal to {2}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.IntegerConverter.MAXIMUM=The number is too high.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.IntegerConverter.MAXIMUM_detail=The number must be less than or equal to {2}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.LongConverter.CONVERT=The number is not a whole number.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.LongConverter.CONVERT_detail=Enter a whole number.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.LongConverter.MINIMUM=The number is too low.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.LongConverter.MINIMUM_detail=The number must be greater than or equal to {2}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.LongConverter.MAXIMUM=The number is too high.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.LongConverter.MAXIMUM_detail=The number must be less than or equal to {2}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.NumberConverter.CONVERT_PATTERN=The format is incorrect.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.NumberConverter.CONVERT_PATTERN_detail=The format of the number must match this pattern: {2}
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.NumberConverter.CONVERT_NUMBER=The value is not a number.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.NumberConverter.CONVERT_NUMBER_detail=The value must be a number.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.NumberConverter.CONVERT_CURRENCY=The currency format is incorrect.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.NumberConverter.CONVERT_CURRENCY_detail=Enter a currency in the same format as this example: {2}
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.NumberConverter.CONVERT_PERCENT=The percentage is not in the correct format.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.NumberConverter.CONVERT_PERCENT_detail=Enter a percentage in the same format as this example: {2}
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.ShortConverter.CONVERT=The number is not a whole number.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.ShortConverter.CONVERT_detail=Enter a whole number.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.ShortConverter.MINIMUM=The number is too low.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.ShortConverter.MINIMUM_detail=The number must be greater than or equal to {2}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.ShortConverter.MAXIMUM=The number is too high.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.ShortConverter.MAXIMUM_detail=The number must be less than or equal to {2}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.ByteConverter.CONVERT=The number is not a whole number.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.ByteConverter.CONVERT_detail=Enter a whole number.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.ByteConverter.MINIMUM=The number is too low.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.ByteConverter.MINIMUM_detail=The number must be greater than or equal to {2}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.ByteConverter.MAXIMUM=The number is too high.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.ByteConverter.MAXIMUM_detail=The number must be less than or equal to {2}.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.DoubleConverter.CONVERT=The value is not a number.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.DoubleConverter.CONVERT_detail=The value must be a number.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.FloatConverter.CONVERT=The value is not a number.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.FloatConverter.CONVERT_detail=The value must be a number.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.ALERT_FORMAT={0} - {1}
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.convert.ALERT_FORMAT_detail={0} - {1}
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.event.FileDownloadActionListener.DOWNLOAD_ERROR=An error occurred downloading the file.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.event.FileDownloadActionListener.DOWNLOAD_ERROR_detail=The file was not downloaded or was not downloaded correctly.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.core.input.CoreInputFile.INPUT_FILE_ERROR=An error occurred uploading the file.
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.core.input.CoreInputFile.INPUT_FILE_ERROR_detail=A file upload error has occurred, please verify your upload data and file name.
```

Answer (score 0):

To override a single message, you can use the convertDateTime element:

```
<af:inputDate id="date1" label="date">
   <af:convertDateTime messageDetailConvertDate="Insert a date"
                       hintDate="Example: 01/01/2001"/>
</af:inputDate>
```

Comment: Please note that OP is using Trinidad, not ADF. Whilst Trinidad is indeed under the covers using the old ADF library, providing a Trinidad-specific example with `tr:` tags would be less confusing for starters.